# Obtaining internal state of a @classmethod in Python

Tags: python, syntax, scope, scoping

I'm using a library inside which there's a following function defined:

```
@classmethod
def from_file(cls, path):

    try:
        with open(path) as config_file:
            content = yaml.safe_load(config_file)
    except IOError:
        log.error(u"Can't open configuration file '%s'" % path)
        raise ConfigurationError

    return cls(content)
```

which I'm invoking in the following manner from my own class:

```
class MyConfig(object):

    def __init__(self, custom_base_path=None, mappings_file_name=None):

    ....
            self.__cfg = self.__load_mappings_file(file=mappings_file_name)

    ....
```

---

```
def __load_mappings_file(self, file=None):

      ....

    return AttrHolder.from_file(filename)
```

`AttrHolder` class is defined within same module:

```
class AttrHolder(Config):
            schema = {
                "subject": {
                    "email": StringEntry,
                    "name": StringEntry
                    },
                "entitlements": {
                    "containerName": StringEntry(required=True)
                    },
            }
```

Here's the code for the 3rd party Config's `__init__`:

```
def __init__(self, content, _schema=None):
    if _schema:
        self.schema = _schema

    if self.schema and (not content or not isinstance(content, dict)):
        log.error(u"Invalid configuration")
        raise ConfigurationError

    self.entries = {}
    self.children = set()

    for key, value in self.schema.items():
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            setattr(self, key, Config(content.get(key), _schema=value))
            self.children.add(key)
        elif isinstance(value, ConfigEntry):
            self.parse_entry(key, value, (content or {}).get(key))
        else:
            log.warning(u"Invalid entry in configuration content: %s" % key)
```

I'm wondering how I can get a hold of the `content` field in that 1st stanza to use inside my class Config?  The reason I need to do this is I discovered (via debugging) that the `AttrHolder.from_file()` invocation returns a mutilated representation of the structure that was passed to it.  I'd like to retain the original representation which seems to be available in the `content` field.

Thank you.

Comment: Does the `from_file(cls, path)` method from your first code snippet belong to the `AttrHolder` class or is this from a different class? And if so, how does the __init__ method of the `AttrHolder` class look like?

Comment: No, it's a different method from an imported library.  `AttrHolder` is defined inside `MyConfig` class.  I pasted the full contents of the `AttrHolder` which is inheriting from the `Config` class in that other library.  I will paste the code for it as well.

Comment: Yes, correct.  I pasted the `__init__` of the `Config` class.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just use your own subclass of `AttrHolder` instead:

```
class MyAttrHolder(AttrHolder):
    def __init__(self, content, _schema=None):
        do_things_with(content)
        super(MyAttrHolder, self).__init__(content, _schema)

...

MyAttrHolder.from_file(filename)
```

Then inside `from_file`, `cls` will be `MyAttrHolder`. That's the point of a `classmethod`.